# PHP error Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: sqlite, xml-parsing, command-line-interface, php

Hello I'm getting the following error

```
Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in file.php on line 113
```

line 113 is     $publish_content=$matches2[1];

This is my code

```
    if(!preg_match('/\<content\:encoded\>(?:\<\!\[CDATA\[)?(.*?)(?:\]\]\>)?\<\/content\:encoded\>/si',$item,$matches2)){
        for($i2=0;$i2<count($info_tag_pairs);$i2++){
            if(preg_match('/'.custom_preg_quote($info_tag_pairs[$i2][0]).'(.*?)'.custom_preg_quote($info_tag_pairs[$i2][1]).'/si',$item,$matches2)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $publish_content=$matches2[1];
    $publish_content=strip_tags($publish_content);
    $publish_content=preg_replace('/'.arrayToString($rkws,'|','custom_preg_quote').'/si','',$publish_content);
    $publish_content=trim($publish_content);
    //echo $item;
    if(!preg_match_all('/\<category\>(?:\<\!\[CDATA\[)?(.*?)(?:\]\]\>)?\<\/category\>/si',$item,$matches2)){
        for($i2=0;$i2<count($category_tag_pairs);$i2++){
            if(preg_match_all('/'.custom_preg_quote($category_tag_pairs[$i2][0]).'(.*?)'.custom_preg_quote($category_tag_pairs[$i2][1]).'/si',$item,$matches2)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the contents of your variables?

Comment: You'd probably do better to change the code to use a real XML parser instead of fighting with dodgy regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to avoid those notices thrown by php is test if the value is set before doing anything with the value.

```
<?php

if (isset($matches2[1])) {
    // do what you need with $matches2[1]
    // ...
}

// or

if ( ! isset($matches2[1])) {
    // here you are sure $matches2[1] doesn't exist
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your array variable `$matches1` doesnt contain key `1`. Since you are accessing `$matches2[1]`, incase `$matches2` is blank or null or has only one value, `$matches2[1]` is an invalid offset.

This can occur if your `preg_match` doest match your `$item`.

Comment: @MSona: We can't tell you that because we have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing. But the top if-statement and loop are clearly wrong in some way, since they allow execution to reach line 113 without `$matches2` having been initialized.